# Vim helptag generation

Tags: vim

I use pathogen and have an update script that downloads the latest versions of all the vim plugins I use from vim.org, github, or wherever else they may be. However, this script does not currently update the vim helptags. In order to do so, I have to go to each updated plugin in vim and execute ":helptags doc/". It would be great if I could do so with my update script, but in order to do so I need to run the vim ":helptags" command from a script. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shouldn't all of the documentation be in the same `doc` directory? Maybe .vim/doc,  /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/doc?

In any case, you can launch vim, and direct it to run a command:

```
cd <plugindir>
vim -c "helptags doc/"
```

You can specify multiple commands, so the last one can be `-c q` to have vim exit when you're done. (Or you can tack it on as one command, `command1 | q`.) Or, if you have many commands to run, you can generate a script, and have vim run it using `vim -S <script>`; again, you can make the last command of the script `q` so it closes when it's done.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I was hoping there was a cleaner way than -c "... | q", because vim whines and complains about being called when stdout is not a terminal, but I fixed that up with a bit of "2> /dev/null". Thanks!

Comment: You could also tack on `-u NONE` to keep vim from doing any initialization like sourcing vimrcs, if you're obsessive (or if your vimrc is really slow).

Comment: The issue here is that [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) keeps each plugin in a different directory inside a common directory (`bundle/` by default), so going into each `bundle/name-of-the-plugin/doc` is annoying. Chris answer below is the appropriate answer.

Comment: If you're not running Pathogen: find ~/.vim -name doc -type d -exec vim -c "helptags \{}" -c q \;

Answer (score 75):

[pathogen.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) versions after 1.2 (2010-01-17) have a `pathogen#helptags` function that will automatically update the help tags for each directory in the `runtimepath`. Just call it after you call `pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles`:

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

Or, assuming you have `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` in your `.vimrc`:

```
vim -c 'call pathogen#helptags()|q'
```

from the command line only once after you have fetched the updates.

---

Recent versions of pathogen recommend calling `pathogen#infect()` in your `.vimrc` instead of `pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles` (since [b147125](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/commit/b1471255528d024e6f7a0103560beb70659b05b1) “Add pathogen#infect() as primary entry point for basic setup”, 2011-05-13; the former calls the latter internally). If your `.vimrc` is calling `pathogen#infect()`, then put your call to `pathogen#helptags()` after that.

Comment: Make sure you have call helptags after appending all the bundles.

Comment: `call pathogen#infect()` is used instead `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()`. Just it case someone else stumble here.

Comment: In your .vimrc 
`execute pathogen#infect();execute pathogen#helptags()`

Comment: You can now also just run the command :Helptags (note the capital 'H'), which runs :helptags on every doc/ directory in your 'runtimepath'.

Answer (score 8):

In recent enough versions, `:helptags ALL` will work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Any idea which minimal version this requires?

Answer (score 4):

For some time [pathogen provides the `Helptags` command](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#runtime-path-manipulation) that updates the documentation of all your bundles (and all other directories that are part of the `runtimepath`).

Thus, it's sufficient to call

```
:Helptags
```

after your Vim plugin collection has changed. Possibly even automatically by calling e.g. `vim -c Helptags -c q` from your update script.