# Vim + Pathogen not loading help docs

Tags: vim, pathogen

Currently I use Pathogen to organize my vim plugins.  It seems to do this fine and without a hitch but for some reason the helptags are not generated.  I don't think my file structure is at fault (although it could be) because as far as I can tell I've set it up correctly, e.g: `pathogen.vim` is in `~/.vim/autoload` and all my plugins are in `~/.vim/bundle`

My `.vimrc` is aliased to the `HOME` directory so I can quickly find it and open it and the pathogen related part looks like this:

```
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles() 
call pathogen#helptags()
```

I feel like I've tried every iteration of this I've found on the internet as well and nothing has been successful.  The plugins seem to work just fine every time but I can never get the help docs using the helptags.  I'm using Mac OSX 10.6 if that helps.

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: try moving the `filetype off` below the `calls`.  In other words put pathogen stuff at the top of the `.vimrc`

Comment: The only thing I have above my pathogen calls in my .vimrc is `set nocompatible`. You might try adding that too.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys.  So I've moved the pathogen calls up underneath nocompatible.  And I also tried moving the filetype off below the calls.  Didn't have success in either.  It just seems odd to me that Nerd tree loads right up but its help files don't.

Comment: If there's any other info I can provide to help find a solution, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: Ok I've narrowed the problem down a little.  It turns out some of my other plugins help files work.  I have four plugins.  vim-rails, vim-ruby, EnhancedCommentify, and NerdTree. The help tags work for vim-ruby (:h ft-ruby-omni and :h ft-ruby-syntax) and EnhancedCommentify (:h EnhancedCommentify) but the other two don't work.  Really weird.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? i'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Nope. Haven't looked at it since my last post so the problem still persists.  I'm glad I'm not the only one having this problem though.  If you find a solution, please post it.

Comment: See "[Vim helptag generation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4180590/128421)" for additional information.

Comment: This may sound really stupid, but for Windows users make sure your `bundle` files are in `vimfiles` instead of `vim74` or whatever it is. All the plugins will work if they're in `vim74`, but not `:Helptags`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim helptag generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180590/vim-helptag-generation)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I had the same problem of not finding the help when updating pathogen - I just had to run the following command to generate the helptags:

```
:Helptags
```

If you simply add the line to start pathogen to:

```
call pathogen#infect()
Helptags
```

It will generate them on startup and you will have the help as always.

Comment: Actually this one worked. The answer provided by jinfeild did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

To quote [tpope](https://github.com/tpope) from the [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) [README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#runtime-path-manipulation):

> Normally to generate documentation, Vim expects you to run `:helptags` on each directory with documentation (e.g., `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`). Provided with pathogen.vim is a `:Helptags` command that does this on every directory in your 'runtimepath'. If you really want to get crazy, you could even invoke `Helptags` in your vimrc. I don't like to get crazy.

Comment: +1 for sharing tpope's humor in the guise of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

On 4/13/2011 a `:Helptags` command was added, which generates help tags along the `'runtimepath'`

The preferred way of initializing the plugin is now:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

All this and more in the [docs](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

Comment: Thanks for your reply jinfield.  I've tried this code in the past and tried it again after I saw your post.  But it wasn't successful.

Comment: This doesn't work. It never calls `Helptags`. @Gjallar's answer works and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my reply to "[Pathogen does not load plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383502/pathogen-does-not-load-plugins/9178061#9178061)". I think it might address your problem. Once you follow what I mentioned there, you should get the documentation for your plugins as wanted.