# Pathogen not generating help tags Vim Windows

Tags: vim, pathogen

I if you have already tried solutions like this one [Vim + Pathogen not loading help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970334/vim-pathogen-not-loading-help-docs) where you only add `filetype off` before calling pathogen infect and you still **CANNOT** generate the help tags, this hint might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathogen is searching for the bundle folder under `~/.vim/bundle`, and generates the helptags for every doc folder, where `~` is your runtime path. On Windows the default runtime path for vim is `~/Vim/vim73` which somehow confuses Pathogen, if you change the runtime path to the previous folder `~/Vim` everything is fixed!

The runtime path variable in Vim is changed using the command:

```
:let $VIMRUNTIME = "puth_path_here/Vim"
```

Type :h $VIMRUNTIME in Vim for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: If you are using vim and windows, this needs to be done.  I spend a long time trying to get my NERDTree help docs working.