# Install vim-go in linux?

Tags: linux, vim, go, installation

I would best be described as a dabbler at this point in linux/vim. I'm trying to get started with go. Trying to install the vim-go plugin and i'm having issues. Following the following [post](http://obahua.com/setup-vim-for-go-development/).

I added the following to the end of my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export GOPATH=~/gocode
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

and created the following directory `~/gocode`

So i created my `~/.vim/bundle` & `~/.vim/autoload` directories. I downloaded `pathogen.vim` to the autoload directory. I cloned the github repository for vim-go into the bundle directory which created a `vim-go` directory.

I created my ~/.vimrc file and added the following:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax enable  
filetype plugin on  
set number  
let g:go_disable_autoinstall = 0
```

I executed the following from the vim console (which worked after installing Hg):

```
:GoInstallBinaries
```

FYI, i don't use vundle and to be honest don't even know what it is :).

So far the plugin doesn't seem to be working. When i type `:help vim-go` i get the following error: `E149: Sorry, no help for vim-go`

What am i do

Comment: Run this command: `:Helptags`, and run `:help vim-go` again.

Comment: @romani thanks that worked fix the help but this point that is the only thing thats working. Syntax Highlighting, ect... is not

Comment: I won't be able to help you further. Maybe you could try vim-go's issue tracker?

Comment: @romainl ok thanks i'll take your advice and do that.

Answer (score 2):

Using the manual install method (copying vim-go/ to ~/.vim) I was able to get it working but only once I had the following ~/.vimrc file, and of course the Go binaries installed as per the instructions.

```
set nocompatible
set shell=/bin/sh
syntax on
filetype plugin on
let g:go_disable_autoinstall = 0
```

This was done on an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with no other vim plugins or prior ~/.vim directory or ~/.vimrc. Frankly the official install instructions and many of the tutorials out there assume to much to be useful on a fresh install of Ubuntu.

However "help vim-go" was still not working for me. Tried the following command from within the ~/.vim directory and got that working: [Vim helptag generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180590/vim-helptag-generation)

Comment: So, I took the whole affair very personally, solved all my problems and scripted it to avoid future issues: https://github.com/paulswanson/congo

Answer (score 2):

solution put that in you .vimrc :

```
set nocompatible   
execute pathogen#infect()  
syntax on  
filetype on  
filetype plugin on  
filetype plugin indent on
```

go in your .zshrc ou .bashrc and put :

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/gocode/"
export PATH=$PATH:~/gocode/bin
```

and in terminal do :

```
source .zshrc
```

or

```
source .bashrc
```

and now go to

```
 cd ~/.vim/bundle
```

and do if youuse pathogen :

```
  git clone  https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.git
```

in vim do :

```
:GoInstallBinaries
```

test one of this commands :

```
:GoFmt
:GoLint
```